# Subtract coins value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to subtract my value and save it.
So for example

500 coins. I created button "Buy". My item cost 80 coins and i want  `(500 - 80)` and value will save.

```
<p id = "coins"> 500 </p>       
<script>
   var coins = 500;
   document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML= (500 - 80);
   document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
     if (coins>80) {
        alert("You successfully bought this item!");
     }
     if (coins<80) {
        alert("You do not have much money");
     }
   }
</script>
```

and doesn´t matter in what language it will be..Even so thanx for help :)

Comment: `coins` is always `500`.

Comment: You can't lower the value of `coins` by using `.innerHTML`. You should just do it with Math. Like `(coins - 80);`.

Comment: Altay- thanx but i want that when i press button...code will read from <p> and <p> value (in my case it is 500) and then subtract 500 - 80 and show alert...

Comment: From `<p>` and `<p>`? I don't see any paragraph here.

Comment: yeah i forgot ...sorry...:) now its there

Comment: why don't you check the inner html instead of a variable that you never change

Comment: So `var coins = 500; ... onclick = function() { coins -= 80; document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML = coins; ... }` ?

Comment: Now <p> is there...and yes...i wasnt come there to listen that my variable never change...i know it...i came there because i want solution...

Comment: Either change your variable or use the inner html for checks ? Isn't that an enough solution. You do ask a common sense question in preconditions already known by you. Your question is like "I have a variable that I don't change, but I want to check it if it changes", well.. it's an question containing the answer itself - change the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I press the button, I'd like to read the coins value from `p` (in my case it's 500) and then, subtract 500 - 80 and show the alert.

```js
var coins = parseInt(document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML, 10);

document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    
    if ( coins < 80 )   {
        alert("You do not have much money");
        return;   
    }
    alert("You successfully bought this item!");
    coins -= 80; // equal to coins = coins - 80;
    document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML = coins;   
}
```

```html
<p id="coins">500</p>

<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: I am glad I could help. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

By using jquery

```
    <p id="coins">500</p>
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Buy" />
   -- Jquery
    $('#button').click(function () {
        var coins = $('#coins').text();
        var rem_coins = coins - 80;
        if (rem_coins > 80) {
            alert("You successfully bought this item!");
            $('#coins').text(rem_coins);
        }
        else if(rem_coins < 80)
        {
            alert("You do not have much money");
        }    
    });
```

Demo [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/boeo5hvx/1/)